# Sort Array from min to max

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, random

I have an array with random elements. there are 10 element in the array.

How to order thesee numbers in the second array from min to max.

examle array (43, 2, 23, 45...)  in second array must be (2, 23, 43, 45...)

code c#

```
int[] mass = new int[10];
int[] mass2 = new int[10]; 

void shemtxvevitimasivi()
{
    label1.Text = "";
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<mass.Length; i++)
    {
        mass[i] = r.Next(0, 100); 
    }
    for (int k=0; k<mass.Length; k++)
    {
        label1.Text+=mass[k].ToString()+" | ";
    }
}

void minim()
{
    for (int t = 0; t < mass.Length; t++)
    {
        label2.Text = mass.Min().ToString() + " | ";
    } 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    minim();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shemtxvevitimasivi();
}
```

Comment: Copy contents of first array to a new array, then sort the new array using [`Array.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at:http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/

Comment: `int[] mass2 = (int[])mass.Clone(); Array.Sort(mass2);`

Comment: int[] a = { 43, 2, 23, 45 };
            int[] b = a.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `.Sort`:

```
int[] mass2 = { 4, 7, 2, 0 };
Array.Sort(mass2);

foreach (int value in values)
{
    Console.Write(value);
    Console.Write(' '); 
}

// outputs 0 2 4 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Linq´s [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-statament:

```
var myArr = mass.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can *create* the second array as a (sorted) *copy* of the first one via *Linq*:

```
  int[] mass = new int[10];
  ...

  int[] mass2 = mass
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement some sorting algorithm yourself, or simply just use:

```
Array.Sort(yourArray);
```

Comment: This modifies the original array and does not produce a second one.

Comment: Can always make a copy of the original array into a new array and then sort that, the question was vaguely worded so I couldn't understand exactly what they required.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] values = { 43, 2, 23, 45 };
int[] ordered = values.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

You can use `OrderBy` to order the elements in ascending order. If you wanted to do it the other way around (order descending) then you can use `OrderByDescending`.